# Spring MVC maven application stopping by if had executed a mvn install command

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging

When i do mvn install on my project, the last line is apperaring and not moving forward and below is my mvn dependencies

-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@632f9712 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

```
<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: war file is not generated even after mvn install command is executed,

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify that your project is a webapp?
You need to put `<packaging>war</packaging>`

in your pom.xml to have install creating a war file.

Comment: Yes have done that , and a day after that my code is running as usual and that error specified is not working